# Emacs Evil keybinding with evil-visual-state-map not working

Tags: vim, emacs

In Vim, I have this keybinding for navigation: `noremap <M-j> 5j`. This will work in **normal**, **visual**, and **visual line** modes.

I want to have the same behavior in Emacs, so I did:

`(define-key evil-visual-state-map "\M-j" '(lambda () (interactive) (evil-next-line 5)))`

`(define-key evil-motion-state-map "\M-j" '(lambda () (interactive) (evil-next-line 5)))`

It will work in **normal** and **visual** mode, but not in **visual line** mode (that is, uppercase **V**).

I'm new to Emacs, coming from Vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looking at the source, let's do that:

```
(evil-define-motion myevil-next-visual-line (count)
"Move the cursor COUNT screen lines down, or 5."
:type exclusive
  (let ((line-move-visual t))
  (evil-line-move (or count 5))))
```

and

```
(define-key evil-visual-state-map "\M-j" 'myevil-next-visual-line)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Now, could you help me with this problem?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519331/emacs-evil-repeat-dot-behavior

Answer (score 0):

If you have

`(defun godown()
  (interactive)
  (evil-next-line 5))
(define-key evil-visual-state-map "\M-j" 'godown)`

then you can do either just add

`(evil-declare-motion 'godown)`

OR you can use

`(evil-define-motion godown ()
  (interactive)
  ...
)`

to replace the `defun` + `evil-declare-motion` combo.

Source: https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issues/395/cant-use-evil-next-line-in-a-script-in-a