# Emacs Evil "repeat" (dot) behavior

Tags: vim, emacs

I have the following line in my `.emacs`

`(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\M-j" (lambda () (interactive) (evil-next-line 5)))`

that makes navigation in a file easier. For instance, with `M-j` I go 5 lines below, so I don't have to press `j` 5 times. I do the same for all `hjkl`. The trouble is that this command pollutes the *last repeat* in Evil (the dot), so let's say I replace a word in a given line, then I do `M-j` to go change a word 5 lines below. If I press `.`, it will jump another 5 lines below, instead of replacing the word as it would happen in Vim. If I use any of `hjkl` though, it won't pollute the *last repeat*. How can I do so that my function doesn't pollute the *last repeat*?

**EDIT:** I just noticed that it doesn't actually happen with `\M-j` and `\M-k`, but only with `\M-h` and `\M-l`, so the problem is even stranger. Both are defined as:

`(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\M-h" '(lambda () (interactive) (evil-backward-char 5)))`

`(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\M-l" '(lambda () (interactive) (evil-forward-char 5)))`

Comment: Hi, no idea, so asking: don't you like to navigate with paragraphs using `{` or `(` or with sexps, using `beginning-of-defun` or `beginning-of-sexp` ? I like them better than using "5 lines up" because they make more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace the lambda with a defun say: `(defun my-5-lines-down...)`and then `(evil-declare-motion 'my-5-lines-down)`
In evil (and probably vim?) motions do not count as repeatables so this should do the trick. Alternatively you can use `evil-define-motion`instead of defun if you want control over the jump list. See [documentation](https://gitorious.org/evil/evil/blobs/raw/doc/doc/evil.pdf) for defining a motion.

Comment: Could you explain why of this behavior? Thanks

Comment: There is no particular reason actually, it is just evil trying to replicate vim's behaviour as always. So yours is not a question about evil, but vim instead, which I don't have an answer. Good thing is there are no downsides with this approach since you can choose whether to declare or not to declare a defun as a motion.